# In eclipse treat macro redefinition as an error rather than a warning

Tags: c++, eclipse

C++

I know some/most will say to treat all warnings as errors but with the code base I am working with that is not currently feasible.
I have two header files generated by an external tool containing addresses of some hardware that I need to access.
e.g.

header1.h

`#define address1  0x123`

header2.h

`#define address1 0x123`

The situation above is not ideal but it is fine, the preprocessor would not generate a warning in this case. However if the second macro def were different I would like that to flag an error and not a warning.
In Eclipse if I were to change that second definition of address1 to be different I will get a warning like:

'address 1 redefined [enabled by default]'

I can't find a warning number or switch that I can use to treat this as an error.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages.  It seems you are actually writing in C++, so please remove the `c` tag

Comment: You want the compiler to give you an error at build time, or you want Eclipse to show you the error before you even build?

Comment: the source of the problem is the external tool.  Suggest the external tool, when it generates `header2.h` to generate: `#define address2 0x123`  OR do not include both headers in the same compilation unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one header defines the address as `0x123` and the other as `0x234`, then if both headers are included in a single translation unit, you will get a redefined macro warning or error. (I code with GCC's `-Werror` so it would definitely be an error for me — it converts all warnings into errors and is, in my view, a good disciplinarian; you have to have warning-free code to get it to compile at all.)  If the warning is enabled by default, you can convert it to an error with `-Werror`, but you don't get the selectivity of `-Werror=missing-prototypes` or whatever.

If you need to keep the values in sync, define the address in one header (e.g. `header1.h`) and have the other (`header2.h`) include the first.  This could be regarded as an application of the maxim DRY (don't repeat yourself), or ODR (one definition rule — though that's more for external symbols than macro definitions), or various other names.

Failing that, in some module, include both headers so that things will fail if you get it wrong (the values are different).  Headers provide the cross-checking in your build system and are crucial.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. To generalize the question, the warning I am dealing with doesn't display a flag or error number, it just says enabled by default with no -Wxxx like I would expect. If I had the flag I could do -Werror=xxxx and treat this warning as an error. I can't figure out why this particular warning doesn't have a flag, and what I can do to get the flag for this particular warning

Comment: It doesn't have the enabling flag because it is deemed compulsory. You are stuck, I'm afraid, with `-Werror` converting all warnings to errors, which I actually think is a good idea as it prevents you from using code that has warnings. I don't compile my own code without `-Werror`. I sometimes suppress it for bad cases of 'code from SO' (but code I post in answers is usually clean). There are 30+ years of legacy issues that prevent me using it on all the code at work, but the parts I'm in charge of mostly compile with `-Werror` enabled (but not with all the supporting warnings that I'd like).

Comment: I was afraid of that but suspected that it might be compulsory though I was hoping even if I couldn't disable it I COULD change it from a warning to an error. Because I'm working with legacy code I can't convert all warnings to errors. Thank you!